# reg exp for Printable characters but string should be not as a blank or white space

Tags: java, junit

I'm using now this reg exp for a max length of

```
255"^[!-~]{0,1}|[ -~]{0,254}$"...
```

But I need one reg exp for printable chars not blank or white spaces?

Comment: 1)Tags are used to indicate what you are asking; this has nothing to do with java and junits. 2) Read the tour of the page to read how this website works! 3) Understand formatting of the given editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 String p = ".{0,255}";
```

this regex will give you the result you want. use like: ``String.matches(pattern)`